# Как хранить многомерный массив в сессии?

Tags: laravel

Я хочу сделать корзину, которая будет храниться в сессии, но я не понимаю, как хранить многомерный массив. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне передать в сессию, и потом получить этот массив.
Пример массива:

```
$flowers = array( array( "Название" => "розы", 
                         "Цена" => 100,
                         "Количество" => 15 
                       ),
                  array( "Название" => "тюльпаны", 
                         "Цена" => 60,
                         "Количество" => 25,
                       ),
                  array( "Название" => "орхидеи", 
                         "Цена" => 180,
                         "Количество" => 7 
                       )
                );
```

Comment: я совсем не знаю Laravel, но из общих соображений - Вы всегда можете превратить json в строку, а строки уже отлично хранятся в key-value коллекции. А при вытаскивании этой строки из сесии - превращать обратно

Comment: @S.H. Я не очень понимаю, как это сделать, но все равно спасибо за идею